# Save and Load Keras/Tensorflow loss function's internal state variable

Tags: variables, tensorflow, keras, center, loss

I am implementing a model in Keras with Tensorflow backend that uses the center loss function defined in the paper [A Discriminative Feature Learning Approach
for Deep Face Recognition](http://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf). I am currently using an implementation of the center loss that I found in [this issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6929) of Keras repository:

```
def _center_loss_func(features, labels, alpha, num_classes,
                  centers, feature_dim):
    assert feature_dim == features.get_shape()[1]    
    labels = K.reshape(labels, [-1])
    labels = tf.to_int32(labels)
    centers_batch = tf.gather(centers, labels)
    diff = (1 - alpha) * (centers_batch - features)
    centers = tf.scatter_sub(centers, labels, diff)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(K.square(features - centers_batch))
    return loss

def get_center_loss(alpha, num_classes, feature_dim):
    """Center loss based on the paper "A Discriminative 
       Feature Learning Approach for Deep Face Recognition"
       (http://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf)
   """    
   # Each output layer use one independed center: scope/centers
   centers = K.zeros([num_classes, feature_dim])
   @functools.wraps(_center_loss_func)
   def center_loss(y_true, y_pred):
       return _center_loss_func(y_pred, y_true, alpha, 
                                num_classes, centers, feature_dim)
   return center_loss
```

I did some testing and this implementation seems to be working, as the classes are being separated and visually clustered around centers. The problem is that **I can't access the centers values after the training.**

I need them if I want to resume the training from a saved checkpoint. The code as it is always initiates the centers as zeros, and that happens because to load a model using [`keras.models.load_model()`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-whole-models-architecture-weights-optimizer-state), I have to provide `center_loss` in the `custom_objects` dictionary. However, I only have direct access to the `get_center_loss` function, that instantiates `centers` as zeros and returns `center_loss`. My idea was to pass a numpy array `initial_centers` to `get_center_loss` and initialize the centers as `centers = K.variable(value=initial_centers)`.

Another possibility would be to move the centers variable to inside a layer or an optimizer, but I have no clue how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like centers is a variable in your code. It looks like it's a tensor. So the value of centers is never getting updated. Try using tf.get_variable to construct centers, and then it'll automatically be saved/loaded to/from checkpoints.

Comment: @Alexandre , As far as I understand, [K.zeros() is equivalent to tf.Variable()](https://keras.io/backend/#using-the-abstract-keras-backend-to-write-new-code), so it should be a variable, right? Anyhow, I will update the question to be a little more specific. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Ah, I see. So the problem in your code is that the value centers created in `centers = tf.scatter_sub(centers, labels, diff)` is never used, so tensorflow does not execute your assignment operation. Putting the definition of loss in a `with tf.control_dependencies([centers]):` block will fix this.